# Logic filtering of data in Excel between two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

So here's a simple Excel question that has turned out to be more complicated than anticipated, so I'll just post it here.

I've logged some data where the input A shall be used to sort which rows are valid. There are +3000 rows so the following figure is just a simplification.

```
| A | B | C | X |
-----------------
| 0 | 2 | 1 |   |
| 0 | 4 | 2 |   |
| 2 | 1 | 7 |   |
| 4 | 9 | 1 |   |
| 3 | 7 | 4 |   |
| 0 | 8 | 2 |   |
| 0 | 7 | 7 |   |
```

My question is how I can copy all rows (or more accurate, their values) which fulfill the demand that `A[i] >= 0` to other cells (X,Y, Z etc.) i.e. filter the raw data- without "FALSE" or blank cells?

Note: the data was logged chronologically according to time, so it is not straight forward to just sort it.

Comment: Could you sort (`Data tab, "Sort"`) out all 0 values in column A then just copy the remaining? This could be made easily into a macro if it must be quickly repeatable.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not that straight forward, in the simplified overview above i've used "0" but really it's more "0,001243" - also the other big problem is that the data i logged according to time, so I cannot under any circumstanses sort (or rearrange).

Comment: Can you not then sort by `greater than or equal to 1` in the sorting options?

Comment: If you are sorting you aren't changing the order of the data, so it will still be chronologically ordered.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but the problem with this solution is that I had more data sets in the horizontal direction, and because the "A" columns (the switches so to say) are different relative to the row number it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VBA code  should work:

```
Public Sub custom_filtering()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    firstcolumn = 1 'The first column of the original data. A=1, B=2, C=3, etc.
    totalcolumns = 2 'The total of columns to be copied
    factor = 1 'The factor to consider a range to be copied
    destrow = 1 ' The row where the copied data starts
    destcolumn = 5 'The column where the copied data starts
    totalrows = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, firstcolumn).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To totalrows
        thecell = wks.Cells(i, firstcolumn)
        If thecell < factor Then
            Range(Cells(i, firstcolumn), Cells(i, totalcolumns)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(destrow, destcolumn), Cells(destrow, destcolumn + totalcolumns))
            destrow = destrow + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Open VBA /Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

On the left side double click on The worksheet, on the right side paste the code.

Set the variables, mainly the one called `factor` to your liking and that's all.

Comment: Besides the logical operater being opposite, it worked like a charm when i changed line 12 to "If thecell > factor Then". Thank you very much!

Comment: @svea I hope it helps you to understand /manage VBA code.